# How to handle web dropdown for below action method & Also How should I write reusable method for such Action?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

How to create Page Object for such element with Reusable Action Method ?

Methods to include:

```
A method to select an option from list dropdown, example: selectFromList(String option)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the image of markup attached not clears the exact situation, because as per HTML markup it seems an input element and in first image it shows a drop-down. But, you can do something like this as reusable method:

```
selectFromList(String option) {
   //use xpath or css selector here
   WebElement selectOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/span/input[@title="+option+"]"))
   selectOption.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code.:

```
 public void selectFromList(String option){
    // Use any locator by which select drop down node could be found
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='select1']"));
    Select select=new Select(element);
    select.selectByVisibleText(option);
    }
```